# Why the Megillah does not mention Ester marrying Achashverosh?

Tags: marriage, megillat-esther, esther--the-woman

The Megillah ([2.16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Esther.2?lang=en)) mentions taking Ester into the Palace, loving here [more than other girls] and crowning her as the queen but no mention of the marriage or being Achashverosh's wife:

> וַתִּלָּקַח אֶסְתֵּר אֶל־הַמֶּלֶךְ אֲחַשְׁוֵרוֹשׁ אֶל־בֵּית מַלְכוּתוֹ בַּחֹדֶשׁ הָעֲשִׂירִי הוּא־חֹדֶשׁ טֵבֵת בִּשְׁנַת־שֶׁבַע לְמַלְכוּתוֹ׃
>   וַיֶּאֱהַב הַמֶּלֶךְ אֶת־אֶסְתֵּר מִכָּל־הַנָּשִׁים וַתִּשָּׂא־חֵן וָחֶסֶד לְפָנָיו מִכָּל־הַבְּתוּלֹת וַיָּשֶׂם כֶּתֶר־מַלְכוּת בְּרֹאשָׁהּ וַיַּמְלִיכֶהָ תַּחַת וַשְׁתִּי׃
>
> Esther was taken to King Ahasuerus, in his royal palace, in the tenth month, which is the month of Tebeth, in the seventh year of his reign.
>
> The king loved Esther more than all the other women, and she won his grace and favor more than all the virgins. So he set a royal diadem on her head and made her queen instead of Vashti.

Do any sources speak about that?

Comment: There is no Ishus between Jews and Non-Jews. Whatever Esther and Achashveirosh had between each other was not a 'marriage' in the religious sense.

Comment: @Salmononius2 I agree in our religious sense, but in his eyes, why not, just as in the Torah Ishmael took women and Eisov etc.

Comment: Yishmael and Eisav are before Matan Torah, first of all. And their wives aren't Jewish either, and there is ishus for non-Jews.

Comment: @Meir I think what he means to say is that from Achashveirosh's perspective, Esther was just like any other woman and therefore marriage would be *legally* binding, even if it's not *halachically* binding.

Comment: @DonielF Sure, but why would we assume that the Torah cares to tell us about what's legally binding or not, if it has no halachic implication (and even would be misleading)? In fact, as far as halachah is concerned, she was an "anusah" and still legally married to Mordechai (עומדת מחיקו של אחשורוש וטובלת ויושבת בחיקו של מרדכי).

Comment: @Meir (Until כאשר אבדתי אבדתי.) I was thinking - is there any other place in which we find Jews "married" to non-Jews in Tanach? The only place I could think of was intermarriage throughout Sefer Ezra, and there, as well, it never explicitly uses any term which indicates marriage (ארש, or לקח, or the like). 10:2 is the closest it ever gets, but it still never discusses marriage outright. I wonder: why does the Gemara need a source that intermarriage isn't halachically binding, when we could derive it from the fact the pesukim never call it marriage?

Comment: @DonielF You have Shimshon and his Plishti wife, where the shoresh לקח is used several times, and you have Shlomo and Bas Paroh, where it says ויתחתן. The Rambam tells us that they converted, but there's no indication of that in the pesukim, so on the contrary, if we didn't know that intermarriage isn't halachically binding, we'd have said that these women didn't convert and that it is binding.